# Swift 4 - animating both alpha and constraint affects other components alpha value

Tags: ios, swift, animation, alpha

I'm running into a weird situation where animating a UIImageView's alpha affects a UIButton which also exists on the same view.

My code:

```
func handleArrowAnimation(_ arrowImage: UIImageView, _ arrowImageXCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint) {

    arrowImageXCenterConstraint.constant = CGFloat(80)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {

        arrowImage.alpha = UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .leftToRight ? 1 : 0.2
        arrowImage.superview!.layoutIfNeeded()

    }) { (completed) in

        arrowImageXCenterConstraint.constant = CGFloat(0)
        arrowImage.alpha = UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .leftToRight ? 0.2 : 1
        arrowImage.superview!.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

I found that removing the call to layoutIfNeeded() prevents the UIButton alpha from changing, but of course it also prevents the arrow from moving - so it doesn't help me much.

The UIButton is not a subview of the arrowImage, and they don't share the same parent view (their parents share the same parent, though).

What am i missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Well that is odd. are you using interface builder? - any chance of old/mixed outlets?

Comment: @Wez - yes, i'm using interface builder (Xcode 9). And that was also my intuition, but unfortunately the arrowImage and the button are defined with a single exclusive outlet each, and the code does not mix their references in any way :(

Comment: When are you calling `handleArrowAnimation()` ?

Comment: @Wez - i'm calling it on viewWillAppear(). I just tried to move the call to viewDidLoad(), but the issue is still there.

Comment: how about on `viewDidAppear()` ?

Comment: Thanks @Wez, I think you just hit some gold there! The button's alpha isn't changing anymore when i'm calling it on viewDidAppear()! Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: No I can't but i did search for the issue and find someone who fixed it this way - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967837/uiview-animating-one-constraint-affects-another-constraint

Comment: Have no idea how you found it so fast... Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently someone else had this issue and the answer is to make sure you start your animations after the view has loaded, for example in the `viewDidAppear()` method.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    handleArrowAnimation()
}
```

[Here is the link to previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967837/uiview-animating-one-constraint-affects-another-constraint) *There does not appear to be any explanation for the strange behaviour at this time.*